# GitHub Pages User Project Custom Domain

Tags: github-pages

I am trying to use the custom domain https://tahdo.app/ for my GitHub project page found at https://votemike.github.io/todo/
I'm most of the way there. But at the moment, https://tahdo.app/ shows a white screen with a console error of `GET https://tahdo.app/todo/static/css/main.3bffc114.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404`.
I assume this means that the https://votemike.github.io is being replaced with https://tahdo.app/ instead of replacing the whole GH Page URL with my custom domain.
I have the 4 A records that GitHub specify, and the CNAME pointing to votemike.github.io as they suggest.
Supplementary info: I'm using create-react-app and gh-pages to deploy to GH Pages
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do I need to update the homepage field in my package.json or something?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to [update the homepage field in my package.json file](https://github.com/votemike/todo/commit/b1980b43dd25d2146fa1b3db4b6d0dc7698d0de4).
Read more about the answer here: https://dev.to/brettcnelson/getting-create-react-app-to-work-with-custom-domains-on-github-user-project-pages-2hp2